# Enumerate the size of a list backwards, but keep the list going forwards

Tags: python, list, readability, enumerate

So I have some code as follows:

```
amount_of_episodes = len(episodes_from_user_show)
for x in episodes_from_user_show:
    print("[{0}] Episode {1}: {2}".format(amount_of_episodes, x.episode_number,
                                          x.name))  # Prints the available list of episodes.
    amount_of_episodes -= 1
```

What it has done is that it takes the length of a list, it iterates backwards until it reaches 0 and the episode name and number from the api I am using is also being printed.

So what I wanted to know is if there was a more readable way of doing this. Something like using enumerate that can display the size of the list going backwards but the content of the list going forwards (if that makes sense)?

Comment: You could do `for i, x in enumerate(episodes_from_user_show)` and then `format(amount_of_episodes - i, ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is to just print `len(values) - index`:

```
shows = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'show_1'},{'id': 2, 'name': 'show_2'}]
for idx, show in enumerate(shows):
    print("[{}] Episode {}: {}".format(len(shows) - idx, show['id'], show['name']))
```

output:

```
[2] Episode 1: show_1
[1] Episode 2: show_2
```